# Move the user-icon to the right in bootstrap navigation menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am creating a navigation menu using Bootstrap. I cannot move the user-icon (has a login and register as dropdown menu items) to the right and stay to the right when the hamburger-menu appears as the viewport size become smaller.

I would appreciate if someone can show me how to achieve this. The HTML code can be found at the link below. Sorry, cannot paste the code here as I don't have enough points to paste more than 2 links.

https://www.findtaxpro.com/content/img/menufix.html

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're familiar with adding break-points to your css as in `@media screen` if not, it's basically a declaration as to at what precise `width` stuff should start move around on your screen, as in this case, the user-img needs to go from left to right, at a certain width of the browser-window:

```
/* when window is smaller than 500px, the icon will move from left to right */

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
        .user-img {
           width: 45px;
           float: right;
         }
}
```

You can set whatever `max-width` you want as to when the .user-img should switch side. Hope this helps.

**Edit:** 
From what I can see, your document setup already takes care of breaking points. So all you would need to add is `float: right;` to your `.user-img` class.

```
.user-img {
 width: 45px;
 float: right;
}
```

Comment: This moves the user icon to the right when the menu is hamburger, although it switches occasionally when the viewport gets smaller.  I can live with it.  Thanks.  How do I get the user-icon stay on the right always.  I added the css in-line and the new html code is here:  https://www.findtaxpro.com/content/img/menufix-1.html

Comment: Just move the `<a href="#" class="navbar-brand user-img" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"></a> ` so that it's right above `<div class="navbar-collapse navbar-right collapse id="defaultNavbar1 aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px"></div>` Don't forget to mark my answer correct if it helped you!

Comment: Hi Crashtor, Thanks so much for your time.  I tried it.  See sample at https://www.findtaxpro.com/content/img/menufix-2.html.  Now the menu becomes too tall when the hamburger menu appears even when there is room for both the hamburger menu and the user-icon to be on the same line.  Any suggestions?  Dan

Comment: Thanks, Crashtor.  Between your input and the input from another person with the first name Ehsan, I was able to fix it.  I cannot find Ehsan's answer, so cannot thank him.  I pulled the user-icon code outside the navbar-header.  I added "class=pull-right" to the dropdown for the user-icon menu, and also reduced the menu choices to avoid a break between the menu items and the user-icon.  I have achieved my desired outcome.  Thanks to you and Ehsan.  You can see the final code at  https://www.findtaxpro.com/content/img/menufix-ehsan-1.html.

Comment: Great, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
.user-img {
    float:right
}
```

to the CSS might help

Comment: I realized my answer was a bit too general, and was in the middle of editing